# Why is append overwriting everything in the list with the new element?

Tags: python, list, append, overwrite

I'm writing a Python script that reads a CSV file and creates a list of deques. If I print out exactly what gets appended to the list before it gets added, it looks like what I want, but when I print out the list itself I can see that append is overwriting all of the elements in the list with the newest one.

```
    # Window is a list containing many instances            
def slideWindow(window, nextInstance, num_attributes):
    attribute = nextInstance.pop(0)
    window.popleft()
    for i in range(num_attributes):
        window.pop()
    window.extendleft(reversed(nextInstance))
    window.appendleft(attribute)
    return window

def convertDataFormat(filename, window_size):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        window = deque()
        alldata = deque()

        i = 0
        for row in reader:
            if i < (window_size-1):
                window.extendleft(reversed(row[1:]))
                i+=1
            else:
                window.extendleft(reversed(row))
                break

        alldata.append(window)

        for row in reader:
            window = slideWindow(window, row, NUM_ATTRIBUTES)
            alldata.append(window)
#             print alldata

        f.close()
        return alldata
```

Comment: Side note: When you use `with open(...)`, you don't need to close the file. In fact, that's one of the advantages of context managers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really difficult to track what you exactly want from this code.  I suspect the problem lies in the following:

```
alldata.append(window)

for row in reader:
    window = slideWindow(window, row, NUM_ATTRIBUTES)
    alldata.append(window)
```

Notice that in your `slideWindow` function, *you modify the input deque* (`window`), and then return the modified `deque`.  So, you're putting a `deque` into the first element of your list, then you modify that object (inside `slideWindow`) and append *another reference* to the same object onto your list.

Is that what you intend to do?

The simple fix is to copy the `window` input in `slideWindow` and modify/return the copy.

Comment: Sorry my code is so confusing. I didn't know that Python passed everything by reference, so I had to make a copy of window and then add it to alldata. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but I'm suspicious it might be similar to this problem http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/appending-object-to-list-overwrites-previous-842713.html.

Comment: Empty link, useless answer.